# Openlayers 3 ol.animation.pan with timeout?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have created a map with ol3 and added ol.animation to "fly" from one city to another. The Animation should start some seconds after clicking the start button. So, it should work like this:

1. The map is centered on a point called "Eifel"
2. Click start-button
3. After three seconds the flight to "Berlin" starts (it will take 2 seconds)
4. Stay in Berlin for 1 second and then fly to "Stuttgart"

The following code nearly works, but it switches to "Stuttgart" directly. I think the problem ist the "map.getView().setCenter(Stuttgart);" at the End. How can I make it work as expected?

```
    // Klick auf Button -> Start
var startflight = document.getElementById('start-flight');

// Flug 1: Eifel > Berlin
startflight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var duration = 2000;
  var start = (new Date()).getTime()+3000;
  var pan = ol.animation.pan({
    source: (view.getCenter(Eifel)),
    start: start
  });

  map.beforeRender(pan);
  map.getView().setCenter(Berlin);
},
true);

// Flug 2: Berlin > Stuttgart
    startflight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var duration = 2000;
  var start = (new Date()).getTime()+6000;
  var pan = ol.animation.pan({
    source: (view.getCenter(Berlin)),
    start: start
  });

  map.beforeRender(pan);
  map.getView().setCenter(Stuttgart);
},
true);
```

Looking forward to your answers,

jsc

Comment: Please if you have your question answered mark it as correct and finish this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
startflight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var duration = 2000;
  var start = Date.now() + 3000;  // use Date.now()
  var pan = ol.animation.pan({
    duration: duration,
    source: (view.getCenter(Eifel)),
    start: start
  });

  map.beforeRender(pan);
  map.getView().setCenter(Berlin);
}, true);
```

But this will fire immediately when you render, after that `setCenter()` call is made.  So the map will just go blank and then render.  Probably a better approach would be to wrap the whole thing in a `setTimeout`.

```
startflight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var duration = 2000;
  setTimeout(function () {
    var pan = ol.animation.pan({
      duration: duration,
      source: view.getCenter()
    });
    map.beforeRender(pan);
    map.getView().setCenter(Berlin);
  }, 3000);
}, true);
```

If you want to then fly to another city, you can just add another panning function.  I would say that if you have a lot of these multi-city pans you'll want to abstract this some more though.

Comment: Thank you very much Timh, this works very well. Sometimes solution is so easy if just thinking to the right direction.